# Play! auto test with another profile

Tags: testing, playframework-1.x

I am interested in running auto-test with another profile:

```
play auto-test --%specialconfig
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may do it but your profile must start with test-  so you can do --%test-specialconfig